# Simulate log system for input in a neural network

Tags: python-3.x

I have a log file that has been captured from some system and I would like to simulate the log stream with the timestamps included already in the file like they are produced from a virtual server running on my laptop. So after that I can input each line (in fact each log event happening) in a neural network for classification. Is it possible to happen in some way? And I would like this to be done using python.

The log file is in this format:

```
Dec 10 06:55:46 LabSZ sshd[24200]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for ns.marryaldkfaczcz.com [173.234.31.186] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Dec 10 06:55:46 LabSZ sshd[24200]: Invalid user webmaster from 173.234.31.186
Dec 10 06:55:46 LabSZ sshd[24200]: input_userauth_request: invalid user webmaster [preauth]
Dec 10 06:55:46 LabSZ sshd[24200]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 10 06:55:46 LabSZ sshd[24200]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=173.234.31.186 
Dec 10 06:55:48 LabSZ sshd[24200]: Failed password for invalid user webmaster from 173.234.31.186 port 38926 ssh2
Dec 10 06:55:48 LabSZ sshd[24200]: Connection closed by 173.234.31.186 [preauth]
Dec 10 07:02:47 LabSZ sshd[24203]: Connection closed by 212.47.254.145 [preauth]
Dec 10 07:07:38 LabSZ sshd[24206]: Invalid user test9 from 52.80.34.196
Dec 10 07:07:38 LabSZ sshd[24206]: input_userauth_request: invalid user test9 [preauth]
Dec 10 07:07:38 LabSZ sshd[24206]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how you want the lines to be classified?

Comment: this is not exactly the problem for now but I would like to input them in time windows (dont know the exact time window yet). I would like at first to simulate the stream in order to be fed later in a lstm probably.